# How does this hex number convert into an ascii string?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

Im in the middle of going over an assembly "output" of some code i wrote and i have a difficulty in understanding something:

the program loads the ASCII string of "213456435" to the EAX Register.
After it loads it, it shows that eax has the value of: 006F1638 and next to it its written: ASCII "213456435".
I cant understand how does 006F1638 represent the "213456435" ASCII string?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `006F1638` is probably the address at which this string resides.

Comment: What tools are you using? How did you get this assembly, what is the original code? Are you going over a simple assembly file, or are you looking at it in a debugger like `gdb`?

Comment: Oh. Your'e right! I guess i got confused between LEA and MOV. Thanks!

Comment: explain please how you load a string with 9 or 10 bytes into a 32 bit register?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding basics of bits and bytes and what an ascii string is and what a value is and what human readable formats of said bits, are.